# Inline styling not being affected by media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, inline

I am having an issue regarding media queries.

For example I have one line with an inline style included

```
<h1>Hello<span style="font-size:80px;">WORLD</span>

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 180% !important;    
    }    
}
```

The 'Hello' changes based on the media query, but the span 'WORLD' is still the same font size.

Is there anyway I can change this with solely HTML and CSS?

Comment: It should be 180% of what? ...the body or h1 or span?

Comment: WHY do you have inline-styles? Why not just have it all in the CSS? Inline styles override anything you put in the stylesheet, so unless you start using `!important`... But since you try to override it in the CSS using @media-queries, why not just have the original style in the CSS as well?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write selector like this:

```
h1 span{
    font-size: calc(80px *1.8) !important;/* or just 144 */
}
```

You can't just use 180% because it will calculate size based on the size of font before inline style was applied (unless it is what you intended to do).